# FacesServlet denies acces when using Web Services on Google App Engine

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, jsf-2

I'm developing a sample application with Google App Engine over Java that uses Web Services.
Everything works well when I work in the local enviroment, the server service is deployed in my google account and the client is deployed in my local environment.

The problem comes when I deploy the application on Google App Engine and try to execute it. An exception occurs when the backing bean tries to create an instance of the server client:

This is the exception I get:

```
    javax.el.ELException: /home.xhtml at line 20 and column 64 action="#{bergeData.obtenerListado}": java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

    Caused by:
    java.security.AccessControlException - access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:370)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:323)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:49)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:134)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:127)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
    at com.beeva.client.gen.AutomovilServerAPIService.<init>(AutomovilServerAPIService.java:46)
    at com.beeva.controller.AutomovilServletClient.<init>(AutomovilServletClient.java:35)
    at com.beeva.gae.BergeData.obtenerListado(BergeData.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
    at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:937)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:271)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:675)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-98b41701563e1bbd(Request.java)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:375)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:564)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1479)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.findClass(ReflectionNavigator.java:519)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.findClass(ReflectionNavigator.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget(RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:51)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:77)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:253)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:440)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl$2.run(ProviderImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl$2.run(ProviderImpl.java:218)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:34)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.getEPRJaxbContext(ProviderImpl.java:217)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.<clinit>(ProviderImpl.java:88)
    ... 55 more
    `
```

The trace of the exception starts in this line of code:

```
AutomovilServletClient clienteService = new AutomovilServletClient();
```

AutomovilServletClient has a constructor which initializes the API service:

```
public AutomovilServletClient() {
      this.automovilAPI = new AutomovilServerAPIService().getAutomovilServerAPIPort();
  }
```

First goes to the constructor of AutomovilServerAPIService:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "AutomovilServerAPIService", targetNamespace = "http://server.beeva.com/", wsdlLocation = "http://1.XXXX.appspot.com/AutomovilServerAPIService.wsdl")
public class AutomovilServerAPIService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL AUTOMOVILSERVERAPISERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(com.beeva.client.gen.AutomovilServerAPIService.class.getName());

    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            URL baseUrl;
            baseUrl = com.beeva.client.gen.AutomovilServerAPIService.class.getResource(".");
            url = new URL(baseUrl, "http://1.XXXX.appspot.com/AutomovilServerAPIService.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.warning("Failed to create URL for the wsdl Location: 'http://1.XXXX.appspot.com/AutomovilServerAPIService.wsdl', retrying as a local file");
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        AUTOMOVILSERVERAPISERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

public AutomovilServerAPIService() {
        super(AUTOMOVILSERVERAPISERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION, new QName("http://server.beeva.com/", "AutomovilServerAPIService"));
    }

}
```

In the method AutomovilServerAPIService() is where I lose track of the execution. I have checked the content of the constant AUTOMOVILSERVERAPISERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION and it's correct.

Anyone has an idea of why it happens when it is deployed up to Google App Engine?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: Trying the [SOAP example of Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap) I have found that the problem comes with use of Java Server Faces Servlet. My project is a Google Web Application Project with JSF capabilities. So this line in the web.xml is what causes the problem:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**However, I have no idea how to fix it :(**

**UPDATE 2: 
SOLVED!! I have found that the problem is a incompatiblity of GAE with Apache MyFaces JSF-Core 2.0. When adding JSF Capabilities via properties/Project Facets, select JSF 2.0 (Mojarra 2.Z.X-FCS) instead of Apache MyFaces**

Answer (score 0):

I tried example at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/soap and it is working both locally and online.

The changes i made before online deployment were:

- For Server application changed url in wsdl file
- For client application changed url in SOAPService.java

I think second change you have already done.

Can you confirm whether you have updated WSDL file before deploying online?

```
<service name="TestSOAPService">
  <port name="TestSOAPPort" binding="tns:TestSOAPPortBinding">
     <soap:address location="**http://CHANGE_TO_ONLINEID.appspot.com**/testsoap"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

Comment: Yes, both server and client has the same value for the WSDL file location. However, I didn't try the example of google developers. I'll build it and see if there is any diference. Thanks for that :)